# Methods of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Is integration by parts the best method to solve the integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \ln(x)dx$? or should i rather use the Feynman differentiation under the integral sign trick?

Comment: What qualifies one method as better than another?

Comment: Integration by parts is nice in that you can apply it off the bat, and it works nicely for pretty much any $\int f(x) dx$ for $f$ the inverse of a well-known and differentiable function. Feynman integration probably can work for a large class of integrals, but the issue is setting up the parameterization needed; I don't know if there are general rules you should follow for that, though. I guess $\int_0^1 \ln(ax) \, dx$ would be the setup? But especially for more complicated functions, it's hard to say. It's basically a tradeoff of "I know this will work, even if longer" versus "this is cooler"

Comment: Though I suppose that, since Feynman's trick basically amounts to making and solving a differential equation, in some sense it's longer, so I find it hard to think of a way in which Feynman integration might be "better" here, other than it looking cooler.

Comment: @PrincessEev I think the OP may have had $\left.\partial_a\int_0^1x^{a-1}dx\right|_{a=1}$ in mind. Anyway, substituting $y=-\ln x$ is yet another option.

Comment: @J.G. That should perhaps be called "the replica trick".

Comment: The classical simple method : write your integral $\int_0^1 u v' dx$ with $u=\log x$ and $v=x$, then apply integration by parts...

Comment: @user619894 As in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_trick)? I guess it's both.

Comment: Why not use $\int_0^1 \ln xdx = -\int_\infty^0 e^xdx = -1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most standard way to solve it would be to just use parts and Calc II strategies. Leibniz rule seems just overkill.

$$\int^1_0\ln(x)\cdot 1\text{ d}x=\ln(x)\cdot x\Big|^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{1}{x}\cdot x\text{ d}x=(x\ln(x)-x)\Big|^1_0=-1$$